# What did Fyodor Shtein report after his voyage?

Tags: russia, science, california, age-of-sail, exploration

In 1820 The Russian admiralty sent two pairs of ships to explore the polar regions. The [southern ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Russian_Antarctic_Expedition), *Mirny* and *Vostok*, circumnavigated Antarctica, and the northern ships, *Otkrytie* and *Blagonamerennyi*, reconnoitered the Arctic.

German scientist Fyodor Shtein (Friedrich Stein) was the naturalist on the *Blagonamerennyi*. The published accounts of two officers on his ship particularly mention his exploration of California.

As appointed naturalist on a naval expedition, Shtein probably made some report after the ships returned to St. Petersburg. What did he record?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks at this point that this might be another non-answerable. I have found indications that some information from this voyage was never *publicly* published, and *geologic history* may have not been popular to the orthodox based ruling class at the time (Shtein was a German, not Russian). Some information, such as the drawings by Karneev seem to be lost, so perhaps the report concerning the California segment of the voyage is as well. (the visit to Australia has been found and translated [Branagan, 2010](https://royalsoc.org.au/images/pdf/journal/143_Branagan.pdf) )